# Question about the case function is mysql: split value from one field to two

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I got a business task to split one field to two:

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cal_participants.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as memberfirst,

This works. The output is a 4 digit number which is an area code, e.g. 7591.

Now, I need to make a CASE function to return the actual location name, and associate the location with a team.

I've tried this:

```
(CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cal_participants.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as memberfirst = 7591 THEN "Europe"
END)
```

And I need to make an alias on the above location (when 7591 is Europe then "Europe as team_name)

```
SELECT 

cal_participants.participant_id as "member_id",

cal_participants.name as "member_name",

cal_meeting.meeting_id as "reference",

cal_meeting.created_at as "date",

cal_meeting.startdatetime as "start time",

cal_meeting.enddatetime as "end time",

cal_meeting.status as "status",

cal_meeting.deleted_at as "deleted time",

campaigns.name as "campaign name",

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cal_participants.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as memberfirst,

(CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cal_participants.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as memberfirst = 7591 THEN "Europe"
END)


FROM cal_meeting

JOIN cal_participants on cal_meeting.participant_id = cal_participants.participant_id

JOIN campaigns on cal_meeting.campaign = campaigns.id
```

What I want is:

1) The function to return "Europe" when memberfirst is 7591

2) Associate that (Europe) with a team

I get this error: 
Error: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, u'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'as memberfirst = 7591 THEN "Test"\nEND)\n\nFROM cal_meeting\n\nJOIN cal_participants \' at line 18')

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  alias for  a column inside   case when

```
(CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cal_participants.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 7591 
   THEN "Europe"
END)
```

eventually you can add alias  after the case when end

```
(CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cal_participants.name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 7591 
   THEN "Europe"
END) as memberfirst
```